# use sql case statement in a adoquery of delphi

Tags: sql, delphi

so i want to calculate a sum of a field using adoquery and case statement in delphi ;
the code i use is this :

```
DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.clear;
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('select STATUT,case  when month(DATE_PAI)=1 then sum(MT) else 0 end  AS m');
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('from table');
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('where  STATUT in( :dd ,:df) and TYPE_QUIT = :l ');
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('group by STATUT');
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.Parameters.ParamByName('dd').Value:=pm;
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.Parameters.ParamByName('df').Value:=pp;
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.Parameters.ParamByName('l').Value:=typeQ;
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.prepared := true;
     DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.open;
```

but i gest an error message :

> syntax error operator absent in the expression case  when
> month(DATE_PAI)=1 then sum(MT) else 0 end

can any one help me please

Comment: I'd try `SUM(case when month(DATE_PAI) = 1 then MT else 0 end) AS m`.

Comment: i did it but the same error message maybe becouse the case statement wont work in adoquery sql

Comment: Has nothing to do with ADO - fix the query against the database you are using.  Most require you to use the aggregate function (here it is SUM) on the result of the CASE not within it's branches.  Both the comment and answer do it the correct way.

Comment: thanks for your comment brian  but when i use the sum without the case statement like this :DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('SELECT STATUT, sum(MT) AS m FROM VERST630');  it works

Comment: ADO for the most part just passes the query to the database to execute. You need to write valid SQL for that database. Delphi doesn't matter, ADO doesn't matter - you need to write a valid query for the database you are using.  The current answer has valid sql for most databases.

Comment: thank you brian and atika i 'll valid the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do :

(group `SELECT` and `FROM` in the same `DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add()`)

```
DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.clear;
DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('SELECT STATUT, SUM(case when month(DATE_PAI)=1 then MT ELSE 0 END) AS m FROM table');
DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('WHERE STATUT in(:dd,:df) and TYPE_QUIT=:l');
DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add('GROUP BY STATUT');
//...
```

Comment: i did it  '(group SELECT and FROM in the same DataModule2.ADOQuery1_630.sql.Add())' but the same error message